# Declare a private method on a public class which takes arguments of private type

Tags: c++, class

I am writing a socket library in C++-17 which has a public class `Socket` (i.e. I declare it in the `.hpp` file). This class is supposed to be the interface between the user and the library.

I have a private type (declared in the `.cpp` file) `Packet` which is used to represent a packet in memory. The type `Socket` has a few private helper methods which take `Packet` as an argument.

If I try to only declare the helper method in the `.cpp` file, the compiler complains that no such member exists. If I try to declare the method in the `.hpp` then I cannot name the argument type as it is supposed to be private.

This is the public class declaration (in `.hpp`):

```cpp
class Socket {
 private:
  // ...private attributes
  // void serialize(Packet p, uint8_t buffer[64]); // This is the helper function. `Packet` is private type
 public:
  // ...constructors and stuff
}
```

This is how I tried to define the function in the implementation file:

```cpp
void Socket::serialize(Packet p, uint8_t buffer[64]) {
 // ...a lot of things
}
```

How should I go about declaring such functions without making the library internals public.

Comment: Do you mean "public" in the sense of *public access specifier* or in the sense of *library internals that are visible in the public header files* (that shouldn't be exposed that way)?

Comment: I want to make class Socket accessible to others without letting them access Packet. I thought declaring stuff in headers makes them accessible to others? Since they would only be including the header and not the implementation files.

Answer (score 1):

You could make `Packet` a nested private class of Socket, meaning it wouldn't be exposed to the users of your library.

```cpp
class Socket {
    private:
        class Packet {
            ...
        };
    public:
        ...
};
```

Comment: Would I be able to use the Packet class in the rest of my library then? Or would it only be accessible inside Socket class?

Comment: It would generally only be available to the Socket class. If you want it to be used across your library your best bet is probably making a header file outside of the libraries include folder, meaning users of your library still wouldn't be able to access it, but inside your library you would be able to access it freely.

Comment: But to declare the helper function of the Socket class, I need access to the Packet type in that header, right? In which case, I would end up including it and then it would become public.

Comment: Yep, that's true actually. I guess one solution would be to create a derivative class `SocketInternal` in which all functionality relating to packets is hidden, you would always use and instantiate Sockets with the internal class, but only ever return the parent class. Of course this would disallow you from exposing a constructor for Socket, but personally I don't really see much of a different solution.

Answer (score 0):

This can be implemented using a [forward declaration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forward_declaration), which takes advantage of the fact that in C++ it is legal to use pointers and references to [incomplete types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-language/incomplete-types).

Here's an example of how it would look in your situation.

#### include/socket.hpp

```cpp
// Public-facing include file

#include <cstdint>

class Packet; // forward declaration

class Socket {
  private:
    // ...private attributes
    void serialize(const Packet & p, uint8_t buffer[64]); // This is the helper function. `Packet` is private type
  public:
    // ...constructors and stuff
};
```

#### private/socket.cpp

```cpp
#include "socket.hpp"
#include "packet.hpp"

void Socket::serialize(const Packet & p, uint8_t buffer[64]) {
 *reinterpret_cast<int *>(buffer) = p.value; // note access of Packet member
}
```

#### private/packet.hpp

```cpp
// Private (i.e., library local) definition of Packet

class Packet {
  public:
    int value;
};
```

The file `private/packet.hpp` is not shipped with the library. Thus, to includers of `include/socket.hpp`, `Packet` will be an [opaque type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opaque_data_type).